# Show that there is a unique $r$ in real separates $A$ and $B$, such that $(-\infty, r)\subset A$ and $(r,\infty)\subset B$.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $A, B$ be two nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, such that the union of the two is $\mathbb{R}$. Assume that any element in $A$ is strictly less than any element in $B$. Show that there is a unique $r$ in real separates $A$ and $ B$, such that $(-\infty, r)\subset A$ and $(r,\infty)\subset B$.

**Proof:**

1. It's not hard to show that $A\cap B=\varnothing$ by assuming not empty then contradiction.
2. Since $A$ is bounded above by any element in $B$, least upper bound exists, call it $u$. It's not hard to show that $(-\infty, u)\subset A$. Proof by contradiction.
3. Similarly, there is a greatest lower bound for the set $B$, call it $l$.
4. Note the union of these two sets is the entire real, so in order to prove the uniqueness of such a separating point, we can assume WLOG $l<u$ (proof by contradiction, then they have to be equal.) since there exists some element between those two boundaries and contained in both sets which contradicts the empty intersection, so we have $l=u$. Uniqueness is proved.

**Is this correct?**

Comment: The statement doesn't make sense. Since both $A$ and $(-\infty,r)$ are sets of real numbers, how can we have $(-\infty,r)\in A$?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the statement

Comment: It's not an element but a containment of a subset

Comment: I see I used the wrong symbol

Comment: My objection is you can't assume wolog l < u.  l and u are not interchangable.  You can prove that $l < u$ leads to a contradiction but that would implie $u < l$ leads to the same contradiction (which it doesn't; it leads to a different contradiction).  Other than that, this is a good outline but I can't evaluate it as a proof without seeing your proofs of these steps.

Comment: It is indeed a different contradiction that's why I said the union is real, otherwise u<l is a contradiction. So I put the sentence first and then assume wlog

Comment: Wlog means "without loss of generality".  A least upper bound is completely different that a greatest lower bound so so there is a heck of a lot of loss of generality.  You can assume it as a case, but you can't assume it wlog.

Comment: Dedekind cuts is the 1st thing which comes to my mind https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dedekind%27s_Theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three steps of your proof (as an outline) are fine but $4$ seems to fall apart.  You say "so in order to prove the uniqueness of such a separating point" but you haven't proven an existence of such a point.  You haven't proven that either $u$ or $l$ are such a point.  By proving $l = u$ that will prove that $l = u = r$ would be such a point but not that it is unique.  You can't assume wlog that $l < u$.  You can prove that if $l > u$ leads to a contradiction (as $u < x < l \implies x \not \in A \cup B$) and that $u > 1$ leads to a contradiction ($l < x <u \implies \exists a\in A; b\in B: b < x < a$).  That would prove $l=u$ which in turn proves $(\infty, r=u)\subset A, (r=l, \infty)\subset B$ is such a dividing $r$.  But it doesn't prove it is unique.

Maybe what you want to say first is that i) if there exists such an $r$ so that $(-\infty, r) \subset A$ and $(r, \infty)\subset B$ that $r$ must be equal to both the least upper bound of $A$ and then greatest lower bound of $B$.  Thus if such a point exists it must be unique. ii) Likewise if $\sup A = \inf B$ then $r=\sup A = \inf B$ would be such a point. iii) And then prove $\sup A = \inf B$.

Comment: Isn't LUB unique

Comment: LUB is the unique least upper bound.  But that doesn't mean it is the unique dividing point.  $e$ is the unique natural logarthim base, and $\pi$ is unique circle circumference diameter ratio.  But that doesn't mean $\pi = e$ just because they are unique *different* things.

Comment: Bounded above then LUB exists.

Comment: Then the lower half is contained

Comment: Same for the other set B. Then show those two are the same point.

Comment: In the earlier part of the proof, LUB only cuts the lower half into A, same for GLB to B. To show it's unique, show they're equal.

Comment: I see what you wrote, it is much clearer but I want to make it shorter. So 1. LUB certainly works for A, same for GLB for B. 2. Since they are equal, A can't go beyond, which means that that's the only option that satisfies the condition.

Comment: And that's how the uniqueness of LUB/GLB helps.

Comment: If there are two sets of LUB and GLB, then we have two points that satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

As you said, it is not difficult to show that

$$\forall (a,b)\in A \times B$$
$$a\le sup A\le inf B \le b .$$

and $$\sup A= \inf B= r $$
else
$$c=\frac {\sup A+\inf B}{2} \in \Bbb R$$ 
and $$c\notin A\cup B. $$

now for any given $\epsilon>0$,

$$\exists (\alpha,\beta)\in A\times B :$$

$$r-\epsilon<\alpha <r <\beta <r+\epsilon $$
thus
$r-\epsilon \in A $ and $r+\epsilon \in B $

which means that
$(-\infty,r)\subset A\;\;$ and $ (r,+\infty)\subset B .$